# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: WHERE parameter "username" has invalid "undefined" value in postman

Tags: node.js, express, routes, sequelize.js, postman

Currently working on a backend in nodejs for a login page. I'm following this tutorial https://bezkoder.com/node-js-jwt-authentication-mysql/

When I try to go to http://localhost:8080/api/auth/signup in postman I get these errors in my server:

[image]
[image]
[image]

set appropriate Header: Content-Type: application/json and I also set body from test to json in postman

I believe it is coming from this snippet of code, but the rest of the code is in the github link if you need more code.

Github link: https://github.com/bezkoder/node-js-jwt-auth

In verifySignup.js:

```
 const db = require("../models");
 const ROLES = db.ROLES;
 const User = db.user;

 checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail = (req, res, next) => {
 // Username
User.findOne({
 where: {
   username: req.body.username
  }
  }).then(user => {
  if (user) {
   res.status(400).send({
    message: "Failed! Username is already in use!"
   });
   return;
  }

 // Email
 User.findOne({
   where: {
    email: req.body.email
   }
  }).then(user => {
   if (user) {
    res.status(400).send({
       message: "Failed! Email is already in use!"
     });
    return;
   }

   next();
 });
});
};
```

In auth-routes.js my request to register:

```
 app.post(
 '/api/auth/signup', 
 [
   verifySignUp.checkDuplicateUsernameOrEmail,
    verifySignUp.checkRolesExisted
  ],
 controller.signup
);
```

Server.js (all code):

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();

 var corsOptions = {
 origin: "http://localhost:8081"
};



app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// routes
require('./app/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./app/routes/user.routes')(app);

// database
const db = require("./app/models");
const Role = db.role;

//db.sequelize.sync();
// force: true will drop the table if it already exists
db.sequelize.sync({force: true}).then(() => {
console.log('Drop and Resync Database with { force: true }');
initial();
 });

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
res.json({ message: "Welcome to bezkoder application." });
});



// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
 console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});

 function initial() {
 Role.create({
  id: 1,
  name: "user"
 });

 Role.create({
  id: 2,
  name: "moderator"
 });

 Role.create({
  id: 3,
  name: "admin"
 });
 }
```

Comment: Can you add your request body to the question? Also, have you set up a body-parser in your express-app?

Comment: I added my server.js and where I make route api for user register. Github link is here if you need more code: https://github.com/bezkoder/node-js-jwt-auth

Comment: This looks ok as far as I can tell. Can you add a screenshot of your postman-request or  just a `curl`?

Comment: I added the screenshot in the posts

Answer (score 1):

You're sending an empty request body in your POST request. Make sure to pass an object with all the required data:

```
{
  "username": "userNameToSignUp",
  "email": "email@address.com"
  // tbd - other fields you need
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the exact problem you were facing, using the same code and I fixed it by simply sending the request as JSON instead of text. On the POSTMAN interface, go to the body tab and toggle 'Text' to 'JSON'

Answer (score 0):

I have implement this code and added more functionality in it which may help you
this is [repository](https://github.com/Arya4514/Node_Shop) with more functionality  and
the problem in your app is that you are sending empty post request which cause error

```
{
 "username": "UserName",
 "email": "email@address.com",
 "password" : "password"
 }
```

the code link you had give is very simple you have uncomment `initial()` function every time i have added condition so when we drop database or run the app you dont have to comment or uncomment the `initial()` function

Comment: This is basically what I've already suggested, right?

Comment: yes,and i have implemented the demo which he mentioned above